# What does 'REX' stand for in an x86-64 REX prefix?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, machine-code

From [Intel's SDM](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf), section 2.2.1 specifies that the REX prefix is used to:

- Specify GPRs and SSE registers.
- Specify 64-bit operand size.
- Specify extended control registers

But what do the letters REX stand for in the acronym?

Comment: Based on other names, I'd give a guess of register extensions.

Comment: probably similar to the R in RAX: [What does the 'R' in x64 register names stand for?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127668/98103), [What does the R stand for in RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RSI, RDI, RBP, RSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10995349/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This 2002 [Hot Chips presentation](https://www.hotchips.org/wp-content/uploads/hc_archives/hc14/3_Tue/26_x86-64_ISA_HC_v7.pdf) by AMD expands the acronym on slide 10: "REX (Register Extension)".

Kevin McGrath and Dave Christie, "The AMD x86-64 Architecture: Extending the x86 to 64 bits", Hot Chips 14, August 2002.